# Edición necesaria para '¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?'

Tags: soporte, estado-completado

En '[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' hay varios headers que están formateados incorrectamente.

En lugar de

```
### Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico
```

Esta escrito como:

```
###Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico
```

Entonces en lugar de verse asi:

---

#### Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico

---

Se ve así:

---

###Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico

---

Hay alguna forma de que edite la pregunta o tiene que ser alguien con mas reputación?

Comment: Con la etiqueta de estado eleve a los CM para que editaran el documento.

Comment: @gbianchi @ Catija Se que ya la marcaron como estado completado. Solo escribo para avisarles que el primero de los headers sigue sin corregir.

Comment: Cat no lo va a ver.. ahora le aviso.. gracias por avisar... entre a revisarlo y no me di cuenta...

Comment: Catija the first title is still not correct!

Comment: Apologies. Let me know if this is still not fixed!

Comment: @Catija It is, thanks. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Sure! Sorry I messed it up the first time! :D